# Can't launch installed IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, launch

I've just installed IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 11.0.2 on Windows 7 32-bit OS. While trying to run it for the first time I've got the following

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.<init>(UrlClassLoader.java:56)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.<init>(UrlClassLoader.java:50)
    at com.intellij.ide.ClassloaderUtil.initClassloader(ClassloaderUtil.java:122)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:38)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:34)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of     com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName must not be null
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName(FileUtil.java)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.<clinit>(ClassPath.java:55)
... 12 more
```

JDK version is 1.6.0_30-b12. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to download again and reinstall, looks like your installation is corrupted. The problem may be also caused by an antivirus. If it doesn't help provide the full log file: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181.

Answer (score 0):

Finally IDEA had started. Is seems like that was a problem with the name of folder to install. I was trying to install it in D:!install_dir directory and couldn't launch application then, but when I installed it in D:\Program Files\ directory it started without any problems. So I think the exclamation mark caused this problem. Pretty strange but I have no another explanation.